# Django form does not render email field

Tags: python, django

I have a simple password reset form where I take a user's email as input. The relevant class is as below. The code works well on my local machine but the exact code doesn't work in production server. Upon inspecting source of rendered view, I see the value field missing.

Expected o/p is

```
<form method="POST" action="/accounts/password/reset/" class="password_reset">
        <ul class="errorlist"><li>The e-mail address is not assigned to any user account</li></ul>
<p><label for="id_email">E-mail:</label> <input id="id_email" name="email" size="30" type="email" value="someemail@gmail.com" /></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Reset My Password" />
```

In production server, value for the email field is missing. I am totally lost why this may be the case. Any pointers will be appreciated.

```
class PasswordResetView(FormView):
    template_name = "account/password_reset.html"
    form_class = ResetPasswordForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("account_reset_password_done")

    def get_form_class(self):
        return get_form_class(app_settings.FORMS,
                              'reset_password',
                              self.form_class)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(PasswordResetView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ret = super(PasswordResetView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # NOTE: For backwards compatibility
        ret['password_reset_form'] = ret.get('form')
        # (end NOTE)
        return ret

password_reset = PasswordResetView.as_view()
```

Comment: What does `ResetPasswordForm` look like?

Comment: It has some code as showin in this link....                         http://pastebin.com/UCpapEQB                                           class ResetPasswordForm(forms.Form):

    email = forms.EmailField(
        label=_("E-mail"),
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"type": "email", "size": "30"}))

    def clean_email(self):
    def save(self, **kwargs):